# Likelihood of the product of a normal cdf and pdf

Tags: probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, transform

Suppose you had a random sample of r.vs X_i , i= 1....n . What is the likelihood of 2 * pdf(x) * cdf(x) , with pdf and cdf of the standard normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

If by likelihood you mean
$$L(\theta;x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n \{2 F(x_i;\theta) f(x_i;\theta)\}$$
it means that the $X_i$'s are distributed as $\max\{Y_{1i},Y_{2i}\}$, when the $Y_{ji}$'s are iid with density (pdf) $f(\cdot;\theta)$ and cumulative distribution function (cdf) $F(\cdot;\theta)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes thats what I meant by likelihood, but when you do the expansion of it for standard normal pdf and cdf, do you obtain max{y_1i,y_2i}, if so, how did you get this?

Comment: I did not obtain the result from the likelihood itself, but from the fact that the cdf associated with the density $2 F(x;\theta) f(x;\theta)$ is $$F(x;\theta)^2=\mathbb{P}(X<x)^2=\mathbb{P}(X_1<x,X_2<x)=\mathbb{P}(\max\{X_1,X_2,\}<x)$$